# How to map an object to another interface type when the property names are the same using typescript

Tags: typescript

Give I have `IInterface1` and I have an array of objects of this type

```
export interface IInterface1 {
  id: string;
  status: string;
  otherStatus: string;
  title: string;
  person: string;
  needed: IThisOtherInterface[];
}
```

I then have another interface `IInterface2`

```
export interface IInterface2{
      id: string;
      status: string;
      otherStatus: string;
      title: string;
      person: string;
      needed: IThisOtherInterface2[];
}
```

I then want to convert all objects in the array of type `IInterface1` to `IInterface2` the data is the same but I am unable to edit `IInterface1`. How can this be achieved using typescript?

Comment: Are `IThisOtherInterface2` and `IThisOtherInterface` compatible?

Comment: What actual conversion do you want to do? The types look the same to me. Do you have a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question ( Could you please  provide more examples?

Answer (score 2):

If the data is the same, then where is the problem? Types do not exist at runtime. I do not see why

```
list1 as IInterface2[]
```

wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1):

That can be more easier to achieve by just using es6 syntax like:

```
let firstTypeObject = {
  id: 1,
  status: "Active",
  title: "Mr"
};

let secondTypeObject = {...firstTypeObject};
```